# Lazy loading Bitmap Images in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, lazy-loading

Lazy loading, I am using custom **ListView** to display Images and some text. Images are in string format. I'm converting string to Bitmap and assigning to **ImageView**, how to use lazy loading for Bitmap string Images?

Comment: what do you mean by converting string to bitmap?  The string is the resource name?  The string is a url?

Comment: image is converted to string while saving in database and in Activity I am getting string and converting to image using bitmap and displaying in ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Various libraries are available for lazy loading of image. Picasso & Glide are very good. Integration is also very easy. You can use Picasso if image quality is most important. Use glide for faster loading. Though you can prefer anyone, I recommend to use Glide.

For swapped images there may be a problem in async loading of images. How do you know about thread completion. Any thread can load image anytime.

Thanks